# Can you get the type of generic variable

Tags: generics, rust, instanceof, typeof

I want to run code based on a type parameter `T`. `T` can be one of a list of known types.

```
fn test<T>(t: T){
    // if T = u64 print "Hi"
    // if T = u32 print "Sorry"
}
```

Comment: Let me try that last comment again: [Here's a possible application](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9295f44151b9c0d3b1cea6b33236b99&version=stable&mode=debug) of the duplicate to your question. You'd presumably want to add additional behavior to the trait, or add bounds to the `test` function, to be able to do much else.